# What is the meaning of putting あれ at the end of these statements?

Tags: grammar, puns

I saw an ad for Indeed today that had a couple tag lines with an あれ at the end, and I don't understand their use:

求人募集【きゅうじんぼしゅう】にサーチあれ。

仕事【しごと】、バイトさがしにサーチあれ。

Normally I'd assume that あれ would be something like して, since サーチ is a n-する verb, but that's obviously not the case here. I know あれ has several meanings, but usually it just means "that". Are these sentences saying "That with which jobs are searched," or is this a separate meaning or colloquialism I'm not familiar with?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Those are pun-based catchphrases for the job search service by the name of サーチ.

First of all, 「あれ」 is the ***imperative*** form of 「ある/有る」; therefore, it is a verb.  In case someone is wondering, this 「あれ」 has no relation to the 「あれ」("that") as in 「これ/それ/**あれ**/どれ」.

In fact, the two 「あれ's」 are even pronounced quite differently -- 「あれ{HL}」 for the verb and 「あれ{LH}」 for the demonstrative pronoun.

> 「Noun + あれ」 means "Let there be [noun]!"

One of the nouns that are most often used in the expression above is 「幸{さち}」 ("happiness").  So, for instance, 「君{きみ}に幸あれ！」 means "***Wish you happiness!***", "***Much happiness to you!***", etc.  To the newly weds, we often say 「お二人{ふたり}に幸あれ」.

Now, 「サーチ」, as in searching on the internet, sounds sort of like 「幸{さち}」 except for the length of the first syllable, which makes this pun work.  You are turning the common phrase 「幸あれ」 into an advertisement catchphrase 「サーチあれ」 for the job search company.

> "Let there be Search for recruiting staff!" ←　「求人募集にサーチあれ。」
>
> "Let there be Search for job-hunting!" ←　「仕事、バイトさがしにサーチあれ。」

Comment: 今、その利口なシャレが分かります。ありがとうございます。

Comment: Even more so, it’s turning the entire phrase 「Xにさ[あ]ちあれ」into a pun—instead of 君, the サーチ is wished upon 求人募集 in the same way that happiness is wished upon you. (**Edit:** Oh, you were adding this into your answer as I was commenting.)